# Silverlight Applications - How are they updated?

Tags: silverlight

I'm new to Silverlight and am curious how a Silverlight application is updated from one version to the next. Is ClickOnce used to do this, or are there other, hopefully transparent simple and reliable, ways of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using a standard Silverlight application (not out of browser), your regular HTTP rules are respected. So assuming caching is sensible, the latest version will be downloaded from the server automatically when the page is launched.

As for when it is running out of browser, Tim Heuer has a good blog post outlining it:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-offline-update-framework.aspx

Basically, a programmer can request for updates from the server and have the application update itself if necessary.

Comment: @Program X- I would be running this in the browser. So from your explanation, a client would never recognize an update has occurred? This would be great, and unlike ClickOnce.